# strongly connected components for spoj's BOTTOM

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I am trying to solve
http://www.spoj.com/problems/BOTTOM/

Here are the steps I am following:

1) Find the strongly connected components using Kosaraju's algorithm. 
2) Consider a strongly connected component. Consider an edge u. Now consider all edges from u to some vertice v. If v lies in some other SCC, eliminate the whole strongly conected component. Else include all the elements in the solution.

However, I am constantly getting **WA**. Please help.

Here is my code:

```
struct Graph{
    int V;
    vector<int> *adj;
    vector<int> *auxiliary;
    vector<vector<int> > components;


    Graph(int _V)
    {
        V=_V;
        adj=new vector<int>[V+1];
        auxiliary=new vector<int>[V+1];
    }
    void addEdge(int u, int v)
    {
        adj[u].push_back(v);
        auxiliary[v].push_back(u);
    }
    void DFS(int u, bool *visited,stack<int> &nodes)
    {
        visited[u]=true;
        int t;
        stack<int> state;
        bool present;
        state.push(u);
        while(!state.empty())
        {
            t=state.top();
            visited[t]=true;
            present=false;
            for(vector<int>::iterator it=adj[t].begin();it!=adj[t].end();it++)
            {
                if(!visited[*it])
                {
                    visited[*it]=true;
                    state.push(*it);
                    present=true;
                }
            }
            if(!present)
            {
                nodes.push(state.top());
                state.pop();
            }

        }
    }
    void DFSutil(int u,bool *visited,set<int> &members)
    {
        visited[u]=true;
        stack<int> state;
        int t;
        bool present;
        state.push(u);
        while(!state.empty())
        {
            t=state.top();
            present=false;
            for(vector<int>::iterator it=auxiliary[t].begin();it!=auxiliary[t].end();it++)
            {
                if(!visited[*it])
                {
                    visited[*it]=true;
                    present=true;
                    state.push(*it);
                }
            }
            if(!present)
            {
                members.insert(state.top());
                state.pop();
            }
        }
    }
    void kosaraju()
    {
        bool visited[V+1];
        memset(visited,false,sizeof(visited));
        stack<int> nodes;
        int i,t;
        //store the nodes, 1st DFS
        for(i=1;i<=V;i++)
        {
            if(!visited[i])
                DFS(i,visited,nodes);
        }
        //run DFS on the auxiliary(transposed) graph
        set<int> members;
        vector<int> answers;
        memset(visited,false,sizeof(visited));
        while(!nodes.empty())
        {
            t=nodes.top();
            members.clear();
            if(!visited[t])
            {
                DFSutil(t,visited,members);
                set<int>::iterator it;
                for(it=members.begin();it!=members.end();it++)
                {
                    vector<int>::iterator itt;
                    for(itt=adj[*it].begin();itt!=adj[*it].end();itt++)
                    {
                        if(!present(members,*itt))
                            break;
                    }
                    if(itt!=adj[*it].end())
                        break;
                }
                if(it==members.end())
                {
                    for(it=members.begin();it!=members.end();it++)
                        answers.pb(*it);
                }
            }
            nodes.pop();
        }
        sort(answers.begin(),answers.end());
        tr(answers,itt)
            printf("%d ",*itt);
        printf("\n");
    }

};
```

Comment: You should construct a few non-trivial test cases by hand and see if those give you the output it should. You'll probably learn a lot more from that than you would from someone else pointing out your mistake (which I believe don't conform to [so] guidelines in any way).

Comment: I did create a few test cases...those mentioned in questions+self created. Could you recommend some test cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, it looks like your depth-first search (assuming DFS is supposed to be depth-first) might not actually be depth-first, but rather a breadth-first-search, since it adds all of the unvisited neighbors to the search queue immediately.  I think you might need to add a break statement:

```
for(vector<int>::iterator it=adj[t].begin();it!=adj[t].end();it++)
        {
            if(!visited[*it])
            {
                visited[*it]=true;
                state.push(*it);
                present=true;
   -----------> break;
            }
        }
```

In comments, sudeepdino008 correctly pointed out that DFS can be implemented with a stack, but in this case I believe that vertices shouldn't be marked as visited until they are removed from the stack:

```
for(vector<int>::iterator it=adj[t].begin();it!=adj[t].end();it++)
        {
            if(!visited[*it])
            {
   ---------->   //visited[*it]=true;
                state.push(*it);
                present=true;
            }
        }
```

Here's the problem:  Consider a simple graph

```
1->2
1->3
3->2
```

With the original algorithm, vertices will be added to `nodes` in the order `(3,2,1)` rather than `(2,3,1)`.  This means that, in the second part of the algorithm, when the backwards BFS is performed, `2` will be selected before `3`, and the algorithm will incorrectly output that `(2,3)` is a strongly connected component.

Comment: No. DFS is implemented using a stack. Though I am pushing all the elements, I am using only one of them for the next time.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, however, I believe that if you want to implement it that way, you don't want to mark vertices as visited until you actually take them out of the queue.  Something like this: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~heap/270F02/node36.html

Comment: Hmmm...interesting...Let me check it.

Comment: Well, that is embarrassing that I didn't had my DFS implementation straight. I don't think I could have figured out the mistake as I as was looking at a different place. Thanks man! great eye!